# I'm confused in writing data from a file into a one dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, assign

For example I read in a file containing;

```
12354343 12 12 35 87 48 100 65 435
45395893 23 12 65 45 23 098 44 233
12902440 23 09 20 04 40 054 00 100
```

How would I place the first line in the 1st element, the second line in the 2nd element of the array and so on?

I've opted out code just to do a openfile check to make sure my file is opening which it is
but I'm not sure whats going on with the rest

```
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
const int data = 50;
int ray1[data];

int Id,score1,score2,score3,score4,score5,score6,score7,score8,mid,lab,codelab,finalT;
cout << "Stdnt Id  ----- Assignments -----  Mi  Ex  CL  Fin" << endl;
cout << "________  _______________________  __  __  __  ___" << endl;
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("assign1Input.txt");
 if (inFile)
{
    while (inFile >> Id)
    {
       for(Id = 0; Id < 50 ; Id++)
       {
         cout << Id << setw (2) << score1 << setw (1) << score2 << setw (1) << score3
         << setw (1) << score4 << setw (1) << score5 << setw (1) << score6 << setw (1) << score7
         << setw (1) << score8 << setw (2) << mid << setw (2) << lab << setw (2) << codelab
         << setw (2) << finalT << endl;
       }
    }
    inFile.close();
}
else
{
    cout << "ERROR" << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can do `inFile >> array[i]`.

Comment: yeahh that crashed codeblocks i must be a pretty bad programmer haha

Answer (score 1):

```
vector< vector< int > > data;
ifstream file;
string line;
while (getline(file, line))
{
    data.resize(data.size() + 1);
    ostringstream ss(line);
    int x;
    while (ss >> x)
    {
        data.back().push_back(x);
    }
}
```